# Custom WinForms button does not change image?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a custom Button, called AcceptButton, inheriting from System.Windows.Forms.Button

On the constructor I set a few properties, but most important, an image (A green checkmark), like this:

```
this.Image = Proyecto.Controls.Bases.Properties.Resources.ok_16;
```

When I add this control using VS2013 form designer, in another project that references the DLL I just created, the image is displayed correctly. But if I go into my control, and change the image in code, for example, to:

```
this.Image = Proyecto.Controls.Bases.Properties.Resources.ok_32;
```

The image is not changed in the projects that use this control (even if the solution is cleaned and regenerated). I followed the code generated by VS2013 and I found that the designer adds this line:

```
this.botonAceptar1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("botonAceptar1.Image")));
```

For some reason, this resource is "hardcoded" in a resource file generated by VS, but it's not updated when I regenerate the solution.

Removing this line makes it work as expected (I can change the image in the "upstream" class and it'll be updated when the solution is regenerated).

Why is this happening?
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens due to the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) attribute. Try adding this property and these methods ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to your class:

```
public class MyButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    public bool ShouldSerializeImage()
    {
        return !object.ReferenceEquals(this.Image, _BaseImage);
    }

    public void ResetImage()
    {
        this.Image = _BaseImage;
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public new Image Image
    {
        get { return base.Image; }
        set { base.Image = value; }
    }
    private Bitmap _BaseImage;
    public MyButton()
    {
        _BaseImage = Proyecto.Controls.Bases.Properties.Resources.ok_16;
        this.Image = _BaseImage;
    }
}
```

This replaces the default `Image` property and prevents the serialization you encountered. Furthermore it allows the designer to check if the property has it's default value and if it needs to be serialized. The default value is stored in a private field in the button class. This should correctly serialize (or not serialize) the properties.

Remove all buttons you have, recompile, readd the buttons to make sure.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The designer still adds the  this.botonAceptar1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("botonAceptar1.Image"))); line in design.

Comment: Ok I saw the difference that the image in your implementation is in a different assembly than the one where you use the button. Designer serialization is a bit fiddly, I'll see if I can find a workaround.

Comment: @hjf This should work now, at least it does for me. This doesn't add your resource line to the Designer file, as long as it is left at its default value. When the image is set from Visual Studio, it will add the line correctly.

Comment: It works now, except for private Bitmap _BaseImage; which i changed to Image instead.