# How to add image or background image to custom button in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

i am pretty new at making custom controls.
I have tried to create a custom button but i can not add background image or image to my button at properties. I don't know why. I have search about this i did not find a solution now asking to you.

Here my codes:

```
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace exampleApp.GUI
    {
     class ThemedButton : Button
     {
      public ThemedButton()
      {           
          BackColor = buttonDefaultBackColor;
          FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
          ForeColor = buttonDefaultForeColor;
          Padding = new Padding(5, 2, 5, 2);            
      }
      protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs args)
      {
          args.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
          TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
          TextRenderer.DrawText(args.Graphics, Text, Font, new Point(Width + 3, this.Height / 2), ForeColor, flags);
      }
      protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
      {
          base.OnMouseEnter(e);
          BackColor = buttonMouseEnterColor;
          ForeColor = buttonMouseEnterForeColor;
      }
      protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
      {
          base.OnMouseLeave(e);
          BackColor = buttonDefaultBackColor;
          ForeColor = buttonDefaultForeColor;
      }
      protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          base.OnMouseDown(e);
          BackColor = buttuonMouseDownBackColor;
          ForeColor = buttonMouseEnterForeColor;
      }
      protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          base.OnMouseUp(e);
          BackColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 133, 7);
          ForeColor = buttonMouseEnterForeColor;
      }
      //Color Settings
      private Color buttonDefaultBackColor = Color.FromArgb(245, 153, 17);
      private Color buttonDefaultForeColor = Color.Black;
      private Color buttonMouseEnterColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 133, 7);
      private Color buttonMouseEnterForeColor = Color.White;
      private Color buttuonMouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 84, 7);
     }
    }
```

i have tried this solution : [Custom WinForms button does not change image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996685/custom-winforms-button-does-not-change-image)

but still not works. Can you please help me ? i want to learn how to design custom button in proper way.

Comment: Did you tried this `YourButtonName.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\folder\image.jpg");`

Comment: You paint over any any image: `args.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);`

Comment: @Taw yes i just realised that.Could you please give me an idea to how to handle this? I want to show an image then text near of it.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes i have tried but it does not work because of i am painting over any image.

Comment: Simply don't draw/fill that rectangle. The Backcolor will be used by default before any other graphics.. - If the defaults are not nice enough you can use TexRenderer to draw the text and DrawImage for the image

Comment: @TaW that works.Lol.that's the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" You paint over any any image: args.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height); " this is the answer that works thanks to TaW

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add 2 lines to your OnPanit function. If you want to make it more generic, create a filePath property and pass it to it in the Image.FromFile (filePath) function.
Tell me if I could help you please?

```
   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs args)
        {
             args.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
            TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(args.Graphics, Text, Font, new Point(Width + 3, this.Height / 2), ForeColor, flags);
            this.Image =Image.FromFile(@"C:\\Users\\Orbus\\Documents\\WorkSpace\VisualBasic6\\PCustomer\\Image\\Search.jpg");
            base.OnPaint(args);
        }
```

Comment: TaW's comment already works.I have tried something like your codes. With this way i have to add picture to every single button. I don't want that.All i want is regular button properties in custom buttom.